# GIT returning fatal "[tag] already exists" error when Deleting then Recreating Tags

Tags: git, gitlab, git-tag

In GIT, I am trying to execute a series of GIT commands to delete an existing tag then recreate it.  However, it is returning a "**fatal: tag '2.0.1' already exists**" error.  Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong or what command I'm possibly missing?

I am executing the following sequence of commands:

```
git clone git@git.someaddress.com/test_project project_dir
cd project_dir
git push --delete origin 2.0.1
git tag 2.0.1 -m "Recreated tag"
```

Currently to work around this, after I execute the push --delete command, I'm deleting project_dir and recloning the repo to create the tag, which isn't very efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also have to delete your local copy of the tag:

```
git tag -d 2.0.1
```

Deleting it from the remote does not delete it from your local repository.